Crashes When run MapmyIndiaMap Widget on Older Android Devices and iOS Simulator in Flutter
I've encountered an issue with my MapmyIndiaMap widget and controller in my stateful class.
Here is my widget:
Expanded(
  child: MapmyIndiaMap(
       initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
       target: LatLng(state.position.latitude,
                     state.position.longitude),
       zoom: 14.0,
      ),
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      myLocationTrackingMode:
      MyLocationTrackingMode.NoneCompass,
      onMapCreated: (map) async {
         _mapController = map;
         await _mapController?.addSymbol(
          SymbolOptions(
            geometry: LatLng(
                      state.position.latitude,
                      state.position.longitude,
                     ),
                   ),
                 );
                  setState(() {});
                  },
       onMapClick: (point, coordinates) async {
            log("Map Point: $point");
            log("Coordinates: $coordinates");
            await _mapController!.addSymbol(
                   SymbolOptions(
                       geometry: LatLng(
                                coordinates.latitude,
                                coordinates.longitude,
                                ),
                    ),
                   );
            },
          ),
),

Whenever I enable these two options:
myLocationEnabled: true,
myLocationTrackingMode: MyLocationTrackingMode.NoneCompass,

The app crashes immediately after the map loads, especially on older Android devices running versions below Android 11 or 12. The error occurs consistently on Android 13 and later versions.
Here is Error:
W/System.err( 2824):    at com.mapmyindia.mapmyindiagl.MapboxMapController.access$000(MapboxMapController.java:108)
W/System.err( 2824):    at com.mapmyindia.mapmyindiagl.MapboxMapController$1.onStyleLoaded(MapboxMapController.java:311)
W/System.err( 2824):    at com.mapmyindia.sdk.maps.MapmyIndiaMap.notifyStyleLoaded(MapmyIndiaMap.java:1614)
W/System.err( 2824):    at com.mapmyindia.sdk.maps.MapmyIndiaMap.onFinishLoadingStyle(MapmyIndiaMap.java:300)
W/System.err( 2824):    at com.mapmyindia.sdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1766)
W/System.err( 2824):    at com.mapmyindia.sdk.maps.MapChangeReceiver.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapChangeReceiver.java:198)
W/System.err( 2824):    at com.mapmyindia.sdk.maps.NativeMapView.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(NativeMapView.java:1122)
W/System.err( 2824):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2824):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
W/System.err( 2824):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:199)
W/System.err( 2824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
W/System.err( 2824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2824):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
W/System.err( 2824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
E/libc++abi( 2824): terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::PendingJavaException
F/libc    ( 2824): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 2824 (com.example.run), pid 2824 (com.example.run)
Process name is com.example.run, not key_process

Additionally, the iOS simulator crashes as soon as the map loads.

Welcome to stackoverflow. This question needs some edits to make it answerable. Source code should be formatted and wrapped in three backtick characters (```). This will enable syntax highlighting. The same goes for error messages. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting
